# Html Floating Issue CSS with image and div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

we want the book my show at left side 
The Ultimate way for Booking Movie Tickets  line should be below to bookmyshow logo image 
callus logo should be right side of the body 
For Enquiry and Call us 922568543 should be  below to callus logo image
how to do it please help me 
 and please teach little bit floating and clear tag

```css
#logo{
  float:left;
  }
h5{
  float:right;
}
#callus {
  width:50px;
float:right;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta  charset = "UTF-8" 
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id= "logo" src="https://d1zx4fn8ox8446.cloudfront.net/filemanager.rboxfile/a72a0f2192d2448a9519561599f7cad2/51a6ee7d-fe24-4f60-b473-675d29399e1e.png" >
    
    <img id= "callus" src="http://www.identivenfc.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/a/call-us-nfc-tag-lg.png">
    <h5> For Enquiry<br> Call us 922568543 
</h5>
    <p>The Ultimate way for Booking Movie Tickets</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to isolate the contact information from the rest of your header content, like so:

```
<header>
---------------------------------------------
                                             |
<img>, <p>                     <aside>       |
 ___________________________    _________    |
|                           |  |         |   |
|                           |  |         |   |
|                           |  |         |   |
|___________________________|  |_________|   |
                                             | 
---------------------------------------------
```

You do this by putting all of the content you want to push to the other side in a parent tag, which you can then `float` to the `right`. In this case, I used `<aside>` as the parent element of the content I want to move.

I've added a background color to the `header` element to demonstrate how the content within the `aside` element floats to the right and is a child of `header`, not `body`.

```css
header {
    background:whitesmoke;
}

header aside {
    float:right;
}

#callus {
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width: device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The Ultimate Way for Booking Movie Tickets</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <aside>
            <img id= "callus" src="http://www.identivenfc.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/a/call-us-nfc-tag-lg.png">
            <h5> For Enquiry<br> Call us 922568543</h5>
        </aside>
        <img id= "logo" src="https://d1zx4fn8ox8446.cloudfront.net/filemanager.rboxfile/a72a0f2192d2448a9519561599f7cad2/51a6ee7d-fe24-4f60-b473-675d29399e1e.png" >
        <p>The Ultimate way for Booking Movie Tickets</p>
    </header>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use more of CSS flexbox to avoid issues with float. Have your top row in one div and assign css flex on the div. Do the same for the lower row.
You can read more on flexbox [here](https://codeburst.io/understanding-css-flexbox-d6162885fefe)

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}  
.lower-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.lower-menu h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  order: 2;
}
#logo{
   height: auto;
}

#callus {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
      <meta  charset = "UTF-8" 
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="top-nav">
  <img id= "logo" src="https://d1zx4fn8ox8446.cloudfront.net/filemanager.rboxfile/a72a0f2192d2448a9519561599f7cad2/51a6ee7d-fe24-4f60-b473-675d29399e1e.png" >
  
  <img id= "callus" src="http://www.identivenfc.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/a/call-us-nfc-tag-lg.png">
</div>

<div class="lower-menu">
  <h5> For Enquiry<br> Call us 922568543</h5>
  <p>The Ultimate way for Booking Movie Tickets</p>
</div>        
        </body>
    </html>
```